# How to get map annotation title in this method

Tags: ios, mkannotation

i want to get annotation title & subtitle from this method.
what the way go get that.

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view{
//NSString * title = [annotations title];
}
```

Comment: `view.annotation.title`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view has an `annotation` property that you can use which will return the annotation you originally used when creating the view.

Comment: But " view.annotation" not return title. Its return "<MKPointAnnotation: 0x7ffdf9c95a50>"

Comment: Yes, it is. Go and check the docs to find out what it is. You should have created it in the first place to give to the view. (also check the superclass docs)